# Errors.add with object instance as message

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form with a custom calendar validation routine. I want to be able to display a lot of dynamic information about the this error to the user.

In this sense `errors.add(:base, "this is wrong because ...")` would not cut it. So I got the idea to pass in an instance of the object that performs the actual validation to the errors array. I would leave it to the view to cherrypick the bits of information it wanted by calling methods on the instance.

In my model validation routine I have:

```
errors.add(:date_range, [calendar] )
```

In the view, I do this:

```
<p><%= @event.errors[:date_range].first.first.parse_events.to_sentence %></p>
```

I had to add the array literal, otherwise the `empty?` method that rails calls would fail.

Even though this works, it smells bad! I thought about using `render_to_string` instead, but obviously that cannot be called (or should not be called) from a model.

Any suggestions on how to improve this?

Comment: Are you trying to validate the calendar using some ajax calls to validate it?

Comment: No Ajax yet, that will come later

Comment: `errors` is just an ordered hash. I haven't tried this and maybe it wouldn't work as I expect , can't we add a new key(error type) - value(string) to it and get the value for the right key in the view and show it ?

Comment: Well, you can pass a Proc as the message (second parameter) to `errors.add`, like: `errors.add(:base, Proc.new { whatever })` and this block gets yielded. However, what I need for my situation is to be able to pass arguments to the Proc...Anyway, I think I will stick with my current solution as it "Just works" ;) Thanks for thinking with me